# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'width', 'height' (WordPress debugging)

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

In the past few days my WordPress installation has been hanging up when I do certain things including:

1. Try to access my media library
2. Try to manage my plug-ins
3. Instruct WP Fastest Cache plugin to empty out the website cache

and so on - so clearly - this is a broader issue.

Naturally, I consulted the website error logs which gave:

```
[22-Jan-2018 15:57:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'width' in /home/ptrcao/public_html/wp-content/themes/independent-publisher/image.php on line 26

[22-Jan-2018 15:57:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'height' in /home/ptrcao/public_html/wp-content/themes/independent-publisher/image.php on line 27
```

Lines 26 and 27 of image.php correspond to `$metadata['width']` and `$metadata['height']` in the context shown below:

```
                        <?php
                        $metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata();
                        printf(
                            __( '"%1$s" - <a href="%2$s" title="Link to full-size image">%3$s &times; %4$s</a> %5$s <a href="%6$s" title="Return to %7$s" rel="gallery">%7$s</a>', 'independent-publisher' ),
                            get_the_title(),
                            wp_get_attachment_url(),
                            $metadata['width'],
                            $metadata['height'],
                            independent_publisher_entry_meta_category_prefix(),
                            get_permalink( $post->post_parent ),
                            get_the_title( $post->post_parent )
                        );
                        ?>
```

Can anyone shed any light on a solution?

Comment: What does `var_dump($metadata);` give you?

Comment: I should have mentioned, I'm just an end user of WordPress, I wouldn't possibly know where to put that code or what to do with it.  Can you please tell me where and how to run this code?  Thank you.

Comment: Put it right below `$metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata();` and right above `printf(`

Comment: Done, and where do I view the result?

Comment: It should be right near your error message when you try the page again

Comment: There's no additional errors or messages in the error log.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: I should mention, no error messages actually appeared on any of the web pages to begin with.  My tasks were just hanging up.  It is not certain if this is the cause of those symptoms, but it was one plausible possibility.

Comment: It's a warning, not a fatal error, so it *should* not cause it to hang. You can try [enabling debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see if that gives you any more information. You can also use [error_log](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) to output the variable to a file to see what it contains.

Comment: In my case, are there specific instructions you are able to offer on how to go about with error_log?  I'm PHP illiterate, so the manual doesn't mean much to me - I can generalise from a manual, but I can follow step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have anything for that right now. Google might be able to give you some tips on using it.

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` will return `false` , when called without `id`,

Comment: did anyone change your theme files? or any updates before you got those errors?

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_metadata() will return false , when called without id` - what did you mean for me to do here?  I didn't understand the point of this - forgive me, my knowledge is very limited here.